# JavaScript encoding sometimes give a different output then C# encoding

Tags: javascript, c#, tobase64string

We want to login on a QNAP NAS via the API and therefor the password needs to be encoded. In the documentation it is stated to use this script to encode: http://eu1.qnap.com/Storage/SDK/get_sid.js

This seems to be a base64 encoding and I want to be able to encode passwords in C# as we are going to call the API's from a C# written backend. So I tried to test the encoding with the following C# code:

```
public static class EncodeHelper
{
    private const string EzEncodechars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

    public static string Utf16to8(string input)
    {
        byte[] utf16Bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input);
        byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8, utf16Bytes);
        char[] chars = (char[])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(char), utf8Bytes.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < utf8Bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            chars[i] = BitConverter.ToChar(new byte[2] { utf8Bytes[i], 0 }, 0);
        }

        return new string(chars);
    }

    public static string Encode(string input)
    {
        var utf8Input = Utf16to8(input);
        var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(utf8Input);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);


    }
}
```

And the most test cases gives the same output. For example: "admin1234" gives "YWRtaW4xMjM0" for both the JavaScript code as the C# code and also our real password is encoded to the same value for both JavaScript code and C# code. But when I try to encode this string: "äçéè", the outputs differs. JavaScript returns "w6TDp8Opw6g=" but C# returns "w4PCpMODwqfDg8Kpw4PCqA==".

It seems that the utf16to8 function isn't the cause of the different output: both JavaScript and C# converts "äçéè" to "Ã¤Ã§Ã©Ã¨" so it seems something different happens in the ToBase64String or GetBytes method. I also tried to encode manually like this:

```
    public static string Encode(string input)
    {
        //var utf8Input = Utf16to8(input);
        //var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(utf8Input);
        //return Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);

        var index = 0;
        var inputLength = input.Length;
        var output = "";

        while (index < inputLength)
        {
            var char1 = input[index++] & 0xff;

            if (index == inputLength)
            {
                output += EzEncodechars[char1 >> 2];
                output += EzEncodechars[(char1 & 0x3) << 4];
                output += "==";
                break;
            }

            var char2 = input[index++];

            if (index == inputLength)
            {
                output += EzEncodechars[char1 >> 2];
                output += EzEncodechars[((char1 & 0x3) << 4) | ((char2 & 0xF0) >> 4)];
                output += EzEncodechars[(char2 & 0xF) << 2];
                output += "=";
                break;
            }

            var char3 = input[index++];
            output += EzEncodechars[char1 >> 2];
            output += EzEncodechars[((char1 & 0x3) << 4) | ((char2 & 0xF0) >> 4)];
            output += EzEncodechars[((char2 & 0xF) << 2) | ((char3 & 0xC0) >> 6)];
            output += EzEncodechars[char3 & 0x3F];
        }

        return output;
    }
```

But the result is the same. My question is: what is causing the difference in output when special characters are used?

Comment: I think it may be due to the encoding.  You are using Encoding.UTF8.  Maybe try Ansii instead.

Comment: Your code is very roundabout with lots of unnecessary and incorrect conversions between encodings as well as strings and bytes. You can’t just create an UTF-8 string as all strings in C# are UTF-16 and trying to just typecast UTF-8 Bytes to UTF-16 chars can’t work. Just do `var utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input); var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(utf8);` to get the base64 encoding of the UTF8 representation of a string.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I will try and look into it. I also noticed I forgot how I called the JavaScript functions. I did that this way: `console.log("encrypted password: " + ezEncode(utf16to8(password)));`